# Is there way to make QPushButton background transparent, but adding icon?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qpushbutton, qt6

Is it possible to make the background of the button transparent, but at the same time to add an icon?

As I understood I should use:

```
button -> setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); ");
```

It works fine, but I want to add an icon too. I have a nice window's background and want to see it through my buttons, but buttons should have icon - black arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using Qt 6 C++. I found a way how to do it:

```
QPixmap buttonImage("/*path*/");
QIcon buttonIcon(buttonImage);
// make the button transparent
button->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); ");
// add icon
button->setIcon(buttonIcon);
```